# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '4K0400

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

the following stored procedure is giving me that above error. how ever when i run each part as a simple query it works fine. what am i not seen? its supposed to get the data of the department for different shifts.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DataByDepartment] 
(
 @referenceDateTime DATETIME
,@shiftsBackward INT
,@shiftsForward INT
,@departmentID int 
)AS BEGIN
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @referenceStartDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @referenceEndDate DATETIME;

SET @referenceDateTime=COALESCE(@referenceDateTime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
SET @shiftsBackward=COALESCE(@shiftsBackward,2);
SET @shiftsForward=COALESCE(@shiftsForward,1);

SELECT 
    @referenceStartDate=MIN(StartDateTime)
    ,@referenceEndDate=MAX(EndDateTime)
FROM dbo.GetShiftsDateTime(@referenceDateTime,@shiftsBackward,@shiftsForward,2);


WITH DataByStockCode AS

(
    SELECT D.StockCode          
         ,D.EntryDate+CAST(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('00000000'+CAST(D.TrnTime AS VARCHAR(10)),8),3,0,':'),6,0,':'),9,0,':') AS TIME) AS DateTime
        ,IM.TrnQty AS Qty
        ,FD.AlphaValue
    FROM [dbo].[Data] AS D
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[FormData] as FD on 
    D.StockCode=FD.KeyField         
    WHERE (             
            (D.TrnYear>=(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1))
            AND
            (D.TrnMonth>=1)
            AND
            (D.EntryDate>=CAST(@referenceStartDate AS DATE))
            AND 
            (D.EntryDate<=CAST(@referenceEndDate AS DATE))              
            AND
            FD.AlphaValue=@departmentID             
        )
)
,ByShift AS
(
    SELECT 
           GWSFRDT.ShiftSequence
           ,BSC.DateTime
           ,BSC.StockCode
           ,BSC.Qty
           ,BSC.AlphaValue
           ,GWSFRDT.StartDateTime AS ShiftStart
           ,GWSFRDT.EndDateTime AS ShiftEnd
           ,GWSFRDT.ShiftPatternName              
    FROM DataByStockCode AS BSC
    INNER JOIN dbo.GetShiftsDateTime(@referenceDateTime,@shiftsBackward,@shiftsForward,2) AS GWSFRDT
    ON(
        (BSC.DateTime>=GWSFRDT.StartDateTime)
        AND
        (BSC.DateTime<=GWSFRDT.EndDateTime)
    )
)
SELECT 
    BBS.ShiftSequence
    ,BBS.DateTime
    ,BBS.AlphaValue
    ,sum(BBS.Qty) as TotalQTY
    ,BBS.ShiftStart
    ,BBS.ShiftEnd
    ,BBS.ShiftPatternName
Group BY ShiftSequence,DateTime,AlphaValue,Qty,ShiftStart
    ,ShiftEnd
    ,ShiftPatternName
END
```

Comment: Can you include the full error output so we at least have a chance of determining where in the stored proc the problem lies?

Comment: I think the error lies in the statement: CAST(D.TrnTime AS VARCHAR(10). But can't say exactly what until post the full error message.

Comment: "Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '4K0400                                                                                              ' to data type int.
"thats the full error

Comment: Well - seeing as 4K0400 cannot be an int, you have the cause of the error right there.

Comment: i am aware of that,but im not seen were im converting a varchar to an int.

Comment: My guess would be an implicit conversion in something like department id to AlphaValue .... but you just need to figure out where you have the data value 4K0400, then you'll also find where you're using it. Should be fairly simple to query your data.

Comment: The '4ko4oo' is an Alpha Value field. how ever i don't see why its doing that because if i'm passing a departmentID of 5 to it,it should only give me the data for that field,when i run it as a query it works fine but as the stored procedure it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

I think the error comes from this line:

```
D.EntryDate+CAST(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('00000000'+CAST(D.TrnTime AS VARCHAR(10)),8),3,0,':'),6,0,':'),9,0,':') AS TIME) AS DateTime
```

I assume EntryDate is a datetime. The plus is interpreted as an addition with a datetime and so the expression after the "+" is implicitly cast to int, because you can't add a time value to a datetime value.
Try

```
DECLARE @time time = '12:00'
SELECT GETDATE() + @time
```

To verify that.

Assuming TrnTime is a time field, simply cast that to datetime:

```
D.EntryDate+CAST(D.TrnTime AS DATETIME) AS DateTime
```

And it'll work fine.

Comment: Only just spotted Allen S. Hansen's comment and your response. I think he's right. On the difference between execution as a query and as stored procedure: the stored procedure probably uses a different execution plan, which will encounter the '04k0400' value. For test I used **create table tab (AlphaValue varchar(50)) insert into tab values (5), ('04k040')** which fails. However, **insert into tab values (5) insert into tab values ('04k040')** works. Try **FD.AlphaValue=CAST(@departmentID AS varchar)** to avoid this.